# Handling "rel hreflang" for specific languages in countries "en-US" and generic languages ex: "en"

Tags: seo, sitemap, language, hreflang, international

If I have 3 english versions of my website:

```
/        FOR USA
/au      FOR AUSTRALIA
/gb      FOR United Kingdom
```

I would add them to my Sitemap using `rel hreflang` to serve those 3 countries:

**Sitemap.xml**

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com</loc>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com"    hreflang="en-US" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/au" hreflang="en-AU" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/gb" hreflang="en-GB" rel="alternate"/>
</url>
```

**QUESTION**

What if I want all english speakers that are not in one of those 3 countries to be led to my `en-US` page, what should I do?

**OPTION #1**

Keep it just like this and let Google decide which is the best version to serve to a english speaking user that is not USA, AU and GB.

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com</loc>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com"    hreflang="en-US" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/au" hreflang="en-AU" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/gb" hreflang="en-GB" rel="alternate"/>
</url>
```

**OPTION #2**

Omit the `en-US` and change it to just `en` so it can get the traffic from USA and also from other countries that speak english other than Australia and UK ?

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com</loc>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com"    hreflang="en" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/au" hreflang="en-AU" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/gb" hreflang="en-GB" rel="alternate"/>
</url>
```

**OPTION #3**

Keep the `en-US` and add a duplicate hreflang to `en`.

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com</loc>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com"    hreflang="en" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com"    hreflang="en-US" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/au" hreflang="en-AU" rel="alternate"/>
  <xhtml:link href="https://example.com/gb" hreflang="en-GB" rel="alternate"/>
</url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #3: use a line for `en`, in addition to the three locale-specific lines. A Google representative [has confirmed](https://www.searchviu.com/en/multiple-hreflang-tags-one-url/) that multiple targets for one URL is allowed.

You do want to target traffic to the appropriate locale-specific site, where one exists. That rules out option #2.

Option #1 would work, up to a point, in that the search engine will still serve your pages for searches outside the explicitly served locales. The snag is that you wouldn't be able to control *which* page is being served to them.